# Python module to keep a file location variable updated?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a variable in my python script that holds the path to a file as a string. Is there a way, through a python module, etc, to keep the file path updated if the file were to be moved to another destination?

Comment: Like to dynamically change your .py file if you move this other file somewhere? Not without considerable effort, if even possible.

Comment: Sounds like the script should accept the path as an argument instead of it being hardcoded

Comment: Yea you could easily implement a file selection dialog box from TKinter or something

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, not with a string.

Long answer: If you want to use *only* a string to record the location of this file, you're probably out of luck unless you use other tools to find the location of the file, or record whenever it moves - I don't know what those tools are.

You don't give a lot of info in your question about *what* you want this variable for; as @DeepSpace says in his comment, if you're trying to make this String follow the file between different runs of this program, then you'd be better off making an argument for the script. If, however, you expect the file to move sometime *during* the execution of your program, you might be able to use a file object to keep track of it. Or, rather - instead of keeping the filepath in memory, keep a file descriptor in memory instead (the kind you would generate by using the `open()` function, and just *never close that file* until the program terminates. You can use `seek` to return to the start of the file if you needed to read it multiple times. Problems with this include that it's not memory-safe, and it's absolutely not a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Your best bet is probably to go with a solution like @DeepSpace mentioned where you could go and call your script with a parameter in command-line which will then force the user to input a valid path.

---

This is actually a really good question, but unfortunately purely *Pythonly* speaking, this is impossible.

No python module will be able to dynamically linked a variable to a path on the file-system. You will need an external script or routine which will update any kind of data structure that will hold the path value.

Even then, the name of the file could change, but not it's location. here is what I mean by that.

Let's say you were to wrapped that file in a folder only containing that specific file. Since you now know that it's location is fixed (theoretically speaking), you can have another python script/routine that will read the filename and store it in a textfile. Your other script could go and get that file name (considering your routine would sync that file on a regular basis). But, as soon as the location of the file changes, how can you possibly know where it is now. It has to be manually hard coded somewhere to have something close to the behavior your expecting.

Note that my example is not in any way a solution to go-to for your problem. I'm actually trying to underline the shortcomings of such a feature.